# Retrieve element value from parsed data in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have the following XML-Structure:

```
<product>
 <id>3482</id>
 <title>Product 1</title>
 <number>1</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>

<product>
 <id>4743</id>
 <title>Product 2</title>
 <number>2</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>

<product>
 <id>3864</id>
 <title>Product 3</title>
 <number>3</number>
 <description>Text</description>
</product>
```

Everything is parsed and saved in my NSMutableArray. Now I'd like to retrieve only the value for the key "title". But when I print my NSMutableArray, I get:

```
"<ChartListDataParserEntries: 0x1edf3c00>"
```

In ChartListDataParserEntries.m I am managing the elements of the parsed XML-File.

I've already tried:

for (ChartListDataParserEntries *CLDPE in self.parsedChartNew) {}

but this is giving me just one single result for one element.

So how can I catch ALL "title"-values (Product 1, Product 2, Product 3...)?

### EDIT

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data delegate:(id <ChartListParserDelegate>)theDelegate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        self.dataToParse = data;
        self.delegate = theDelegate;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)main
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.dataToParse];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    self.dataToParse = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"chart"])
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"new"])
    {
        self.fullyParsedChartNew = [NSMutableArray array];
        chartListDataEntries = [[ChartListDataParserEntries alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"soon"])
    {
        self.fullyParsedChartSoon = [NSMutableArray array];
        chartListDataEntries = [[ChartListDataParserEntries alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!self.parsingResults)
    {
        self.parsingResults = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.parsingResults appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"%@", parseError);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"chart"])
    {
        return;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"new"])
    {
        [self.fullyParsedChartNew addObject:chartListDataEntries];
        chartListDataEntries = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"soon"])
    {
        [self.fullyParsedChartSoon addObject:chartListDataEntries];
        chartListDataEntries = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        [chartListDataEntries setValue:self.parsingResults forKey:elementName];
        self.parsingResults = nil;
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if (![self isCancelled])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.fullyParsedChartNew valueForKeyPath:@"product_title"]);
        [self.delegate didFinishParsing:self.fullyParsedChartNew andChart:self.fullyParsedChartSoon];
    }
}
```

ChartListDataParserEntries.h

```
@interface ChartListDataParserEntries : NSObject
{
    NSString *product_id;
    NSString *product_title;
    NSString *product_genre;
    NSString *product_price;
    NSString *product_stock;
    NSString *product_stock_color;
    NSString *product_stock_text;

    UIImage *product_image;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_genre;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_stock;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_stock_color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *product_stock_text;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *product_image;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
NSArray *titleArray = [array valueForKey:@"title"];
```

This will return an array with all titles.

Comment: Hi ACB. Yes, this would work normally. But there is only one "line" (<ChartListDataParserEntries: 0x1edf3c00>) in it, until I am using the title-element in ChartListDataParserEntries like: `for (ChartListDataParserEntries *CLDPE in self.nsmutablearray) {NSLog(@"%@", CLDPA.title);}`

Comment: Can you please do an `NSLog(@"%@", array)` and share that as it is? It will be easy to understand that way.

Comment: That's what I am talking about :). If I NSLog(); the array, there is only that one line, until I call the "key" for which the value is saved.

Comment: That means that it is not array and it is an object of class `ChartListDataParserEntries`. So do you have an array? Are you doing `NSLog(@"%@", self.parsedChartNew);` itself?

Comment: Yes I do. I added some further code. The results are saved in self.fullyParsedChartNew (NSMutableArray). Now I try to retrieve all title-elements, but I can't catch a list, or even get the index of the items in the array.

Comment: So did you try with `[self.fullyParsedChartNew valueForKey:@"title"];` or `[self.fullyParsedChartNew valueForKeyPath:@"title"];`? Can you please post how you are storing values to `chartListDataEntries` before adding to array? How does it look like?

Comment: Yes I tried, same result (I just get one title). Code is above. But if you say it is an object of class, how can I get all the title elements in one array? I thought a for-loop would do it.

Comment: So are you getting the titles inside one array? I thought you said that it is printing only `(<ChartListDataParserEntries: 0x1edf3c00>) `. If it prints only that much in console then it is not an array. From the code it is very difficult to predict anything.

Comment: Yes, when I search for a key I get one results. What further code do you need?

Comment: Do you have the code which shows how you are filling data to `chartListDataEntries` before adding to array? Right now you are just adding it as `[self.fullyParsedChartSoon addObject:chartListDataEntries];`, but where are you allocating memory for this and how are you setting values in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25829/discussion-between-filou-and-acb)

Comment: I found the error :). It was a wrong placed return;. Now it works like you said. Thanks for your time ACB!